# Parse javascript Blob in golang

Tags: javascript, go

In Go, you can read a form sent using Ajax and [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript#Using_XMLHttpRequest_and_the_FormData_object) using `r.ParseMultipartForm()`, which populates the `Form` map with form request data.

```
func form(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    r.ParseMultipartForm(500) //
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "This is the value of %+v", r.Form)
}
```

However, I haven't found a method to parse Blobs. The above code returns an empty map whenever instead of sending a form, I send a Blob. That is, when I send this:

```
var blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(someJavascriptObj)]);
//XHR initialization, etc. etc.
xhr.send(blob);
```

the Go code above doesn't work. Now, when I send this:

```
var form = new FormData(document.querySelector("form"));
//...
xhr.send(form);
```

I can read form data without problems.

Comment: I think you need to use the json package. Check out this article https://blog.golang.org/json-and-go

Comment: @Snowman The json package helps with encoding and decoding of json data. What I want is to retrieve binary data from an http request. I don't see how that package is going to help in achieving that.

Comment: oh. then I don't get the example JS. It looks as if you're sending a stringify'd object... only way I ever deal with json objects is with package encoding/json.

Answer (score 1):

```
r.ParseMultipartForm(500)
```

Perhaps an error is being returned here? Try capturing the error:

```
if err := r.ParseMultipartForm(500); err != nil {
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
}
```

Also, consider raising the 500 byte memory limit as larger blobs will be written to temporary files.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I did that in my original code. I posted it here without the error checking to simplify it.

Comment: Oh ok. Can you record and add the raw http request you're getting? See [dump request](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#DumpRequest) in httputil

Answer (score 1):

I think javascript treats blob as file, so your can look it in   `r.MultipartForm.File`, get file header, open it, read, decode and parse.
Try for example

```
r.ParseMultipartForm(500) 
fmt.Fprintf(w, "This is the value of %+v", *r.MultipartForm.File)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume Javascript's Blob is a hex string which can eventually be converted to `[]byte`, which is a standard type for JSON in Go.

```
// Once you get the blob
blobString := `7b22666f6f223a205b22626172222c202262617a222c2039395d7d`

b, _ := hex.DecodeString(blobString)
json := string(b)
fmt.Println(json) // prints out {"foo": ["bar", "baz", 99]}
```

You might want to look into `encoding/hex` and `encoding/binary` packages to decode your blob acquired from Javascript to type `[]byte` in Go, if it's not already.

Comment: Maybe, but before that I must be able to actually retrieve that string. My problem is that I don't know where go stores the data that is not sent as a key-value pair, which I believe is my case. In short, Request.Form returns an empty value when I sent a blob.